# labels to comboboxes not appearing for one command but does for other commands

Tags: excel, combobox, label, userform, vba

I'm trying to repair a project that my predecessor had written and I have fixed many of the problems up till now.  I have a user form that works well with many of the comboboxes but I have 6 comboboxes and I'm having trouble with combobox 6. It works well with other commands but there is one command that is not appearing when I choose the relative command in box 5.  Here are the codes:

```
If ComboBox5.Value = "18in or LESS" Then
        ComboBox6.Clear
        Me.Label6.Visible = True
        Me.ComboBox6.Visible = True
        ComboBox6.AddItem "PAPER"
        ComboBox6.AddItem "BOARD"
        Me.Label6 = "PAPER/BOARD"
End If

If ComboBox5.Value = "WIDTH>46in" Then
        ComboBox6.Clear
        Me.Label6.Visible = True
        Me.ComboBox6.Visible = True
        ComboBox6.AddItem "LENGTH > 60in"
        ComboBox6.AddItem "60in >= LENGTH > 22in"
        ComboBox6.AddItem "22in or LESS"
        Me.Label6 = "SELECT LENGTH"
End If
```

Now the PAPER/BOARD works fine but when I choose cb 5 for a different set of commands the corresponding cb6 doesn't appear I just get "label 6" on the user form.  Any type of help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Do you know where Label6 is located? Maybe that control is hidden behind another.

Comment: Thanks I'll check...

Comment: I don't see it hidden behind any other control.  I have about 4 different labels for CB6.  The others work except for the "Select Length" label and command.  Thanks

Comment: If the other label works, I suggest to look for `Label6` control in your `Properties` tab and see the position properties. I guess this control is hidden somewhere.